# HTTP -> HTTPS session transfer issue

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have an issue regarding session transfer from http->https.
I followed the steps which wereposted as an answer in an earlier question.

**HTTP PAGE:**

```
<?php
session_save_path('/home/test/sess_store');
session_start();
$sessionID = session_id();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'Demo session between HTTP HTTPS';
echo '<a href="https://www.mysite.com/test_sess_2.php?session='.$sessionID.'">Demo session from HTTP to HTTPS</a>';

?>
```

**HTTPS PAGE:**

```
<?php
session_save_path('/home/test/sess_store');
$sessionID = $_GET['session'];
session_id($sessionID);
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['test'])) {
echo $_SESSION['test'];
} else {
echo 'Demo session failed';
}

?>
```

However it does not work.. even though i have the same session id on the https page as that on the http.

Ive also checked the pages individually and both store sessions in the same path.. Still i cannot access the session values when i set the session_id on the https page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$_SESSION['test']` is really saved in HTTP?
Try to put that checking block **at the beginning of HTTP Page** and refresh it:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
} else {
    echo 'Demo session failed';
}
```

If it won't work aswell, that means 'test' isn't saved at all, even in HTTP itself - check your PHP configuration file, cause you may have, for example, `session.use_only_cookies=1` value and it won't work thought GET at all.

Let me know if it really works and saves value in only HTTP and if it does, ill try to find the way for it to work in HTTPS aswell.

If you are using **suhosin** patch, check it's configuration aswell, especially `suhosin.session.cryptdocroot` value - try to set it to "Off" it's it's "On".

Comment: $_SESSION['test'] is saved in http checked it.. session.use_only_cookies was 1 .. so used ini_set and set it to 0. still isnt working.

Comment: Still thinking what may couse the problem... in the meantime try to use **PHPSESSID** as your GET key (session_start should use it automatically if it's in GET, you don't need to assign it on variable and put in session_id).

Also i wanted to ask - do you really need session in GET? It should be used only if you can't use cookies. Cookies can also be used through HTTP and HTTPS if they are set correctly.

Comment: i tried using the session_name to set it didnt work... i tried with cookies too.. by passing the session_id in a secure cookie and on the https page used the cookie value to set the session.. didnt work

Comment: If you just redirect to HTTPS page from HTTP and your session cookie is set correctly, you don't need to use it's value to set session again - session_start() should do it automatically. Anyway, if you can use cookies, i suggest you use them and i'll provide some additional informations how to set them correctly in a minute. EDIT: I assume, that it's the same domain, right? www.mysite.com in both HTTPS and HTTP?

Comment: If you'll be trying to set it based on cookies, make sure you have `session.use_cookies=1`, `session.use_only_cookies=1` and `session.cookie_secure=0` and normally session_start() in HTTP, set something in $_SESSION['test'], redirect to HTTPS, session_start there and try to read $_SESSION['test']. Let me know if that works.

Comment: yup its the same domain.. 
when goin from http->https i used a separate secure cookie value( which is nothing but the session id of the session cookie in the http session) to set the session...